# Why is Fourier analysis used in Doppler effect?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, physics

I am a high school student that carried out the experiment on the Doppler effect to therefore analyze the graph but after doing some research, I saw one of the articles saying “ Fourier analysis is a mathematical tool that allows us to extract information about the frequency spectrum of any signal.” I don’t understand, could this be used in my analysis and what does it actually mean?

This experiment was carried out under normal conditions in other words at home and the procedure of this experiment is quite simple where I would be rotating a sound source producing constant frequency in a circular and a smartphone would be recording the data using the app. The results I got shows sharp peaks and frequency ranging from 425 when away from sound source and 441 when in-front of sound source with of course ups and downs due to errors of measurements. The idea is that I am creating a report on how math is used in a real life scenario and so I will be analyzing the graph I got by using different mathematical analysis techniques and therefore this is where I am stuck and looking for what math can be applied to my modeling change in frequency report.

(For my experiment I got sharp peaks of minima and maxima incase you wanted to know what my results were like because unfortunately I have no clue=e how to post my results here)

Reference: [http://www2.york.psu.edu/~kxt7/Labs/Doncheski/doppler/lab01.pdf](http://www2.york.psu.edu/%7Ekxt7/Labs/Doncheski/doppler/lab01.pdf)

Comment: First of all, do you understand what "the frequency spectrum of a signal" refers to?

Comment: No unfortunately I don’t. Could you please tell me what it means and if it is useful in my experiment?

Comment: Second, it would be helpful if you could tell us what exactly the nature of your experiment is. What measurement(s) did you make? What did you try to do with those measurements in order to test a hypothesis?

Comment: I will add that to the question.

Comment: I see from your profile that you've been working on this for a while and have tried asking this question in a few different places; I'm sorry that you haven't gotten much of a response at all. Since you are a high school student, do you have a teacher who you could ask about all this?

Comment: Also, do you have access to any kind of programming language with which to process the phyphox measurements? For instance, would you be able to use python? Could you at least open a .csv file of measurements in excel?

Comment: From a quick look online, [here's the post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51387/computing-the-power-spectrum-density-psd-on-a-csv-file-in-python) I found that comes the closest to doing what you would probably need your software to do. You might have some success asking about this question in the site that post is from, i.e. the [DSP stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I do have a teacher but unfortunately I am student that doesn’t have a good base in math such as other students in my class and so the help I get from my teacher is so limited that the only place I can ask for help is in stack exchange and by researching on my own.

Comment: Also I don’t have an experience with programming so I only used excel and phyphox for my data but if programming would help my report I can always learn it.

Comment: Also yes I will ask the question on DSP stack exchange as you proposed.

Comment: No high school student should be expected to have the mathematical background to handle this project without guidance. I strongly suggest that you contact your teacher and ask how you should move forward with your project

Comment: True I will have to talk to her, but in your opinion, you think I can apply some math such as calculus and more???

Comment: I am asking you this because I want to know if this is a good topic and not waste anymore time because also I know that my teacher is busy so would take around three weeks to set a meeting.

Comment: If the recording is such that you can listen to it and hear the sound source, then it yes it is technically possible to verify the Doppler effect. However, the process of you figuring out how to do so (unless you happen to find some software made for this purpose) is too difficult to be worthwhile. I think that if it's at all possible, repeat the experiment with a louder sound source. Otherwise, I don't think this is a good topic.